Use a metric that is not available in the list of metric for xgboost
Working in R.
I am following this post on stack overflow.
I am train an xgboost model and I want to use another metric that is not in the list of metric we can whoose for the eval_metric parameter.
I want to use the Balanced accuracy and then have fun a bit with the metric. How should I implement it in an existant package (xgboost).
best_param = list()
best_seednumber = 1234
best_logloss = Inf
best_logloss_index = 0

for (iter in 1:100) {
    param <- list(objective = "multi:softprob",
          eval_metric = "mlogloss",
          num_class = 12,
          max_depth = sample(6:10, 1),
          eta = runif(1, .01, .3),
          gamma = runif(1, 0.0, 0.2), 
          subsample = runif(1, .6, .9),
          colsample_bytree = runif(1, .5, .8), 
          min_child_weight = sample(1:40, 1),
          max_delta_step = sample(1:10, 1)
          )
    cv.nround = 1000
    cv.nfold = 5
    seed.number = sample.int(10000, 1)[[1]]
    set.seed(seed.number)
    mdcv <- xgb.cv(data=dtrain, params = param, nthread=6, 
                    nfold=cv.nfold, nrounds=cv.nround,
                    verbose = T, early.stop.round=8, maximize=FALSE)

    min_logloss = min(mdcv[, test.mlogloss.mean])
    min_logloss_index = which.min(mdcv[, test.mlogloss.mean])

    if (min_logloss < best_logloss) {
        best_logloss = min_logloss
        best_logloss_index = min_logloss_index
        best_seednumber = seed.number
        best_param = param
    }
}

nround = best_logloss_index
set.seed(best_seednumber)
md <- xgb.train(data=dtrain, params=best_param, nrounds=nround, nthread=6)
```

